# Render JSON with custom Content-Type in Gin

Tags: go, go-gin

I want to know if it is possible to add a "method" to Gin's context to add the header `Content-Type: application/hal+json` instead of doing it in all API calls `SetHeader`.

Something like this:

```
ctx.HALJSON(http.StatusOK, hal)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`c.Render`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Render) with a custom renderer, that implements [`render.Renderer`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/render#Render).

If the actual rendering is identical to JSON (HAL should be) you can embed `render.JSON` into your struct, so that the method `Render(http.ResponseWriter) error` comes for free, and then implement only the custom content type:

```
type HALJSON struct {
    render.JSON
}

func (HALJSON) WriteContentType(w http.ResponseWriter) {
    header := w.Header()
    if val := header["Content-Type"]; len(val) == 0 {
        header["Content-Type"] = []string{"application/hal+json"}
    }
}
```

And then use it as such:

```
func MyHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    // handler code...
    c.Render(http.StatusOK, HALJSON{})
}
```